# JxBrowser - Render channel already closed - ipc log: OnRenderViewGoneMessage

Tags: jxbrowser

I have a Java application written with Swing that uses a JxBrowser (jxbrowser-6.18).

We are loading a local url (http://localhost:8000/someLink.html) and then running some custom js on the browser.
At some point the following exceptions are thrown in the java code:

```html
CERROR 2019-01-25 07:38:29,801 - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
CERROR 2019-01-25 07:38:29,801 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Channel stream was closed before response has been received.
CERROR 2019-01-25 07:38:29,804 -  at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.SocketChannel.post(SourceFile:216)
CERROR 2019-01-25 07:38:29,804 -  at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.RenderChannelAccessor.post(SourceFile:67)
CERROR 2019-01-25 07:38:29,805 -  at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue(SourceFile:2134)
CERROR 2019-01-25 07:38:29,805 -  at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue(SourceFile:2077)

ERROR 2019-01-25 07:38:29,842 - Render channel is already closed.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Render channel is already closed.
 at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.RenderChannelAccessor.a(SourceFile:72)
 at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.RenderChannelAccessor.post(SourceFile:66)
 at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue(SourceFile:2134)
 at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue(SourceFile:2077)
```

I've checked then the ipc log looking for events that occurred near 07:38:29

```html
#creating browser 
Jan 25, 2019 7:36:50 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.Server start
INFO: Shared Memory Name: TDB2-24864
Jan 25, 2019 7:36:50 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.SharedMemory <init>
INFO: IPC connection has been established. Connection ID: 13818240
Jan 25, 2019 7:36:50 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.MemoryChannelReader a
FINE: READ:  OnHelloMessage{type=OnHello, uid=4, message='cid:0,bid:0,type:Browser', null
Jan 25, 2019 7:36:50 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.Server a
INFO: Channel has been accepted: SocketChannel{cid=0, bid=0, type=Browser}
Jan 25, 2019 7:36:50 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC$b onChannelConnected
INFO: Channel is connected: SocketChannel{cid=0, bid=0, type=Browser}
Jan 25, 2019 7:36:50 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.MemoryChannelWriter run
FINE: WRITE: LoadURLMessage{type=LoadURL, uid=9, url='about:blank', frameId=-1, extraHeaders='null', postData='null', SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Browser}
Jan 25, 2019 7:36:50 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.MemoryChannelReader a
FINE: READ:  OnRenderViewCreatedMessage{type=OnRenderViewCreated, uid=5, renderProcessId=3, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Browser}
Jan 25, 2019 7:36:50 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.MemoryChannelReader a
FINE: READ:  OnFrameCreatedMessage{type=OnFrameCreated, uid=6, parentFrameId=-1, frameId=2, isMainFrame=true, frameName='', SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Browser}
Jan 25, 2019 7:36:50 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.Server start
INFO: Shared Memory Name: TDB3-24864
Jan 25, 2019 7:36:50 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.SharedMemory <init>
INFO: IPC connection has been established. Connection ID: 13816000
Jan 25, 2019 7:36:50 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.MemoryChannelReader a
FINE: READ:  OnHelloMessage{type=OnHello, uid=7, message='cid:0,bid:0,type:Render', null
Jan 25, 2019 7:36:50 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.Server a
INFO: Channel has been accepted: SocketChannel{cid=0, bid=0, type=Render}
Jan 25, 2019 7:36:50 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC$b onChannelConnected
INFO: Channel is connected: SocketChannel{cid=0, bid=0, type=Render}


#loading custom url, executing some javascript, ping messages...
#last messages with cid=0, bid=0 before 07:38:29

Jan 25, 2019 7:37:48 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.MemoryChannelWriter run
FINE: WRITE: PingMessage{type=Ping, uid=420, alive=false, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Browser}
Jan 25, 2019 7:37:48 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.MemoryChannelReader a
FINE: READ:  PingMessage{type=Ping, uid=420, alive=true, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Browser}
Jan 25, 2019 7:37:48 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.MemoryChannelWriter run
FINE: WRITE: GetFrameIdMessage{type=GetFrameId, uid=422, frameId=-1, result=0, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Render}

[...]

Jan 25, 2019 7:38:29 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.MemoryChannelReader a
FINE: READ:  OnRenderViewGoneMessage{type=OnRenderViewGone, uid=388, terminationStatus=6, errorCode=-536870904, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Browser}
Jan 25, 2019 7:38:29 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.MemoryChannelReader a
FINE: READ:  OnFrameDeletedMessage{type=OnFrameDeleted, uid=389, parentFrameId=2, frameId=4, isMainFrame=false, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Browser}
Jan 25, 2019 7:38:29 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.MemoryChannelReader a
FINE: READ:  OnFrameDeletedMessage{type=OnFrameDeleted, uid=390, parentFrameId=2, frameId=5, isMainFrame=false, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Browser}
Jan 25, 2019 7:38:29 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.MemoryChannelReader a
FINE: READ:  OnFrameDeletedMessage{type=OnFrameDeleted, uid=391, parentFrameId=2, frameId=6, isMainFrame=false, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Browser}
Jan 25, 2019 7:38:29 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.MemoryChannelReader a
FINE: READ:  OnFrameDeletedMessage{type=OnFrameDeleted, uid=392, parentFrameId=-1, frameId=2, isMainFrame=true, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Browser}
Jan 25, 2019 7:38:29 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.Server b
INFO: Channel has been disconnected: SocketChannel{cid=0, bid=0, type=Render}
Jan 25, 2019 7:38:29 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC$b onChannelDisconnected
INFO: Channel is disconnected: SocketChannel{cid=0, bid=0, type=Render}
Jan 25, 2019 7:38:29 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.SharedMemory close
INFO: IPC connection has been closed. Connection ID: 13816000
Jan 25, 2019 7:38:29 AM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.SharedMemory close
INFO: Pending IPC connections: 4
```

As we can see from the logs, the Render channel is closing at some point.

OnRenderViewGone - terminationStatus=6, errorCode=-536870904

If you have any ideas in which direction I should look or what does the error code or termination status mean - please tell. I searched for it on the internet but I couldn't find any useful info.

Note that I didn't manage to reproduce the issue, so if you have any ideas on how I could reproduce it, please do tell.

Update1: Here you can find the crash dump file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yx86cfhj5rl2eye/chromium-renderer-2019-Jan-25-07-38-17.dmp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You will get this exception if you try to access Browser instance that is already disposed. For example, if you dispose a Browser instance using the *Browser.dispose()* method and then try to call its *Browser.loadURL()* method, you will get this IllegalStateException error message. Please make sure that in your Java code you don't use already disposed Browser instances. If you use the same Browser instance in different threads, then please make sure that you don't dispose it in one thread and use the already disposed Browser instance in another thread.

To check if the Browser instance is disposed or not, you can use the *Browser.isDisposed()* method.

2) Browser instance was unexpectedly disposed because of an issue in Chromium engine. 
By default, on Windows platforms, when Chromium engine is crashed, JxBrowser generates jxbrowser-chromium.dmp crash dump file and stores it in the %localappdata%\JxBrowser\ directory (e.g. c:\users\\appdata\local\JxBrowser\jxbrowser-chromium.dmp).
Please check this location and share with me all the crash dump files you see using one of the online file sharing services such as Google Drive, Dropbox, etc. Take a look at the [tutorials](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/folders/9000074866) that describe how to get the crash dump files on different platforms.

3) As I can see you are using JxBrowser 6.18 version. I recommend you to update the library to the 6.22.2 as the latest version includes a lot of new features, an updated Chromium engine and plenty of stability fixes, including fixes when connection with the rendering process is lost.

Comment: Hi Serhii, the browser was not disposed (there are no DisposeBrowserMessages in ipc log file, and nor the code should have entered in the dispose flows).
I've checked the crash dump log and here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yx86cfhj5rl2eye/chromium-renderer-2019-Jan-25-07-38-17.dmp (the date and time matches). Please let me know if you find something. Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry for a delay. Yes, I've analyzed the crash dump. The issue is related to the out of memory state which comes from JS. Does your webpage work correctly in an ordinary browser? 
I recommend you to upgrade your JxBrowser version to the latest one (6.22.2 at the moment) and to use JxBrowser in 64-bit mode. Then please try to reproduce the issue and let me know the result.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this. We will upgrade the jxbrowser library in the following month to the latest version available and we'll try to reproduce the problem, maybe even do some stress testing for this component. Thank you again!